# Zentyal Server : Setting up secure VPN Client

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, zentyal

I have officially exhausted pretty much all my google-fu trying to set this up so I'm asking my question here.

For the record, I am a mid level rookie who has played around with servers in his spare time but have never worked with Zentyal Server.

Now, I have been able to set up the server as a gateway, with one Network card being external and the other facing the internal Network.

The Internal network computers are able to access the internet without any issues.

What I need to do is to setup a open-vpn client on the central server so that all Internet data goes though the secure VPN session.

As far as I can see, I can't set up the vpn session through the web admin page.

Could somebody point me in the right direction? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to set this up so you can establish a site-to-site VPN tunnel or allow external clients to VPN to your network and have their internet traffic go through you internet connection?

Comment: Nobody will be connecting to the server externally. I just need all the internal internet traffic to be go over the VPN and not directly on to the servers regular internet connection.

Comment: Essentially, If any of the internal network computers were to google whats my ip? , they need to see the ip of my vpn provider and not the external ip of my server.